# using eclipse 3.6 and GWT and GWT Designer

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwt-designer

I'm trying to create a new GWT project, and want to use the GWT Designer, but can't find the right way. What I've done  is in the docs of google.

step by step:
download and install java, eclipse 3.6, install google plugin in eclipse ( selected everything, I can see the gwt designer in the installed apps list. ), and started a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html). I followed the instructions, except one, ( I don't want to deploy it to Google App Engine, so I unchecked the "Use Google App Engine" checkbox. After a while I thought I should try GWT Designer too, but I can't find a way. I found [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/stockwatcher.html) in the net, but those are for eclipse 3.5, so the menus are different, can't be applied.

So, how can I create a GWT application, without app engine sdk, with gwt designer in eclipse 3.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project, under eclipse, right click on a file you want to edit with GWT Designer and choose Open With > GWT Designer.

Also, as you can see on the screenshot [there](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/quick_start.html), when editing a file in eclipe, you have tabs at the bottom that let you choose which editor/view to use. Make sure you are in the correct view.